# Tips to make only One query?

Tags: mysql

Say I have the following tables:

```
users
-----
id
username


messages
-----
id
sender (id user)
recipient (id user)
msg
```

In a single query, how can I get the name of the sender, the name of the recipient, and the message?

I would basically need to join the users table twice, but not sure how that would be possible..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT
   s.username as sender,
   r.username as recipient,
   msg
FROM
   messages m join users s on (m.sender = s.id)
   join users r on (m.recipient = r.id)
```

Answer (score 5):

You could use the `AS` keyword to give the `users` table a different name when you need to join to it:

```
SELECT `messages`.`id`, `from`.`username`, `to`.`username`, `msg`
FROM `messages`
INNER JOIN `users` AS `from` ON `sender` = `from`.`id`
INNER JOIN `users` AS `to` ON `recipient` = `to`.`id`
```